# Openshift re-rollout failed latest deployment config

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I have the following situation: there is a `Deployment` Config as `YAML` file, which i create with `$ oc create\apply -f filename.yml` The DC has defined `linevess` and `readiness probes`. After 10 minutes the rollout fails with some problem related to environment(not the problem with application inside `Docker` image) After fixing this problem the command `oc apply -f filename.yml` wont do anything because `Openshift` thinks the config remained the same. Is there any option to add to my DC to retry `rollout\start` the `rollout` with the same configuration if and only if the previous was not successful while doing `oc` apply?

Comment: Does the rollout fail or the application crashes. If the live probe fails then openshift should automatically restart the container. That is exactly what that probe is for. You can see that in the amount of pod restarts when running oc get pods

Comment: It's hard to say with this information. You need to provide configuration files (YAMLs). If you have `restartPolicy: always`, they should be restarted if `pod` crash. You could always add `--force` flag to apply command but not sure if this would help in this case.